# Gzip Files: Extracting Does Not Work as Expected

Tags: file, zip, gzip, gunzip

I'm facing this very strange problem when working with gzip files. I'm trying to download this file https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/daily-index/2014/QTR2/master.20140402.idx.gz

When I view the contents of the file inside the archive, it is perfect.

However when I unzip the contents and try to see them, it is all gibberish.

Is something wrong with the file or am I missing to see anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, an idx file is a Java file.  It can also a plain text archive format, which it is in this case.

On Linux, try running

```
gunzip master.20140402.idx.gz
```

This will extract it into an idx file, which you should be able to open with any text reader, such as vi, since vi can open pretty much anything.

On Windows, you can, from the command line, use WinZip, with:

```
wzunzip -d master.20140402.idx.gz
```

You can then use something like IE, Edge, or Wordpad to try to examine the file, that should automagically load a readable environment.

EDIT:

So, I downloaded the file, and was able to extract, and view it in vi, IE, and Wordpad, using my above commands, so if you are seeing gibberish, try redownloading it.  It should be 104kb in .gz format, and 533 kb extracted.

Comment: Actually, I'm downloading this file from a python script using my custom library.. When I download the file manually and try to unzip it, it works fine.